# Ggplot - Coloured Geom Violin with filled Points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to have a plot with x = Species, y = Petal.Length separated by the sepal.width.grouped .
I also want points of Sepal Length to appear on each group of Sepal Width.

I did this but the points are just centered around each specie.

[image: ggplot]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

summary(iris)
iris_example <- iris %>%
  mutate(sepal.width.grouped = case_when(Sepal.Width < 2.8 ~ "Small",
                                         Sepal.Width < 3 ~ "Medium",
                                         Sepal.Width >= 3 ~ "Large"),
         sepal.length.grouped = case_when(Sepal.Length < 5 ~ "<5",
                                          Sepal.Length < 6 ~ "<6",
                                          Sepal.Length >= 6  ~ ">=6"))

iris_example$sepal.length.grouped <- as.factor(iris_example$sepal.length.grouped)

ggplot(iris_example, aes(x = Species,
                         y = Petal.Length,
                         color = sepal.width.grouped)) +
         geom_violin() +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", aes(fill = sepal.length.grouped))
```

Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`geom_violin` is implicitly creating an interaction between the `Species` and `sepal.width.grouped` columns in placing along x axis. You can make this happen in all layers by using an `interaction` perhaps:

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris_example <- iris %>%
  mutate(sepal.width.grouped = case_when(Sepal.Width < 2.8 ~ "Small",
                                         Sepal.Width < 3 ~ "Medium",
                                         Sepal.Width >= 3 ~ "Large"),
         sepal.length.grouped = case_when(Sepal.Length < 5 ~ "<5",
                                          Sepal.Length < 6 ~ "<6",
                                          Sepal.Length >= 6  ~ ">=6"))

iris_example$sepal.length.grouped <- as.factor(iris_example$sepal.length.grouped)

ggplot(iris_example, aes(x = interaction(sepal.width.grouped, Species),
                         y = Petal.Length,
                         color = sepal.width.grouped)) +
  geom_violin() +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", aes(fill = sepal.length.grouped))
```

[image]

Is this approaching what you're looking for?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for ! Thank you so much ! I did not know about this `interaction` term.